# How to keep python process alive - the right way

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've see this question a lot but I'm not satisfied with the answers.
I know server programs like Django and Flask/Werkzeug have startserver/run method that keeps the process alive until a stop signal is received.

I want to implement something similar but I cannot figure out how to do it.
I assume that an eternal loop is a bad way to do it because it is wasted processing time. I'd rather not use a third party library.

My program must stay alive to wait for callbacks, communicate with a server, monitor its internal state, etc.

Pseudocode:

```
import ...

class Main():
    def __init__():
        self.sensors = sensors.register()
        self.database = remote.connect()
        self.running = True

    def start():
    """ this is what I assume is bad """
        while self.running:
            pass

    def stop():
        self.running = False
        self.cleanup()

    def cleanup():
        self.database.disconnect()
        self.sensors.unregister()
```

Comment: You might find this old Python mailing list email useful: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2001-February/089989.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a general paradigm not specific to python to deal with this kind of situation called event loops. If you search for it on the internet, you will find several libraries implementing it. If you use `asyncio` you do not need third party libraries as it ships with python3. I would advise you to familiarize yourself with the concept, the web is full of examples. See e.g. [this](https://tutorialedge.net/python/concurrency/asyncio-event-loops-tutorial/) tutorial. We get this example from there:

```py
import asyncio

async def work():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("Task Executed")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    asyncio.ensure_future(work())
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    print("Closing Loop")
    loop.close()
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any way keep the process alive without a loop?

Comment: This seems similar to how Javascript would listen for events in the browser (eg. click, scroll etc.). There it is also called the Event Loop. It's the main reason js and node are async by default.

Comment: @Anders_K No, it’s not. A process is just a program that executes commands in a sequential order until it is done. To enable multiprocessing, the host OS provides a feature called sleep. While sleeping, a process is idle and does not consume CPU cycles. Under the hood, an event loop uses a loop inside which there is a short sleep and then a check whether sth needs to be done, as a response to an event, for example a signal or a timer event. Also don‘t bother with efficiency when using event loops: The developers spent a lot of effort optimizing. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

```
import time
time.sleep(x) #seconds
```

And only check status at the desired interval.

For network events you could use sockets.
https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/